# Как скомпилировать Vreen (Qt vk api)?

Tags: c++, qt, вконтакте

## Параметры моего окружения :

- `Windows 7`
- `qbs 1.5.1`
- `g++ 4.9.2`
- `стандартный cmd`

Вот ссылка на саму библиотеку на гите : https://github.com/alekseysidorov/vreen

Сначала пытался скомпилить, как написано тут : https://habrahabr.ru/post/157081/ Цитирую  :

```
$ git clone git://github.com/gorthauer/vreen.git
$ cd vreen
$ git submodule update --init

$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
$ make
$ make install (sudo)
```

Но cmake говорит, что нету CMakeLists.txt, что ожидаемо. Посмотрел на самом гите, как надо компилить - цитирую :

### Зависимости:

`C++11 compliant compiler
qbs 1.4 - http://doc.qt.io/qbs/
Qt 5.2.0 - http://qt.io`

### Компиляция :

```
qbs install --clean-install-root --install-root $LOCAL_PREFIX release
```

У меня стоит `Qt 5.7.0` . Я использовал `qbs` из папки `tools` моего `Qt 5.7.0`. Строку для компиляции вставил копи\пастом и нажал enter, находясь в папке `vreen` (коренная папка проекта, скачанного с гитхаба.
`qbs` сообщил мне следующее :

```
ERROR: No profile specified and no default profile exists.
To set a default profile, run 'qbs config defaultProfile <profile name>'.
```

Я последовал его рекомендации и сделал `qbs config defaultProfile prof`

```
ERROR: Unknown or empty profile 'prof'.
```

Может, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой или я что-то делаю не правильно?
Помогите скомпилировать либу.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы указать Qbs расположение Qt build или необходимой версии Qt, их необходимо зарегистрировать. Для **версии** это будет выглядеть так:

```
qbs setup-qt /usr/bin/qmake myqt
```

Вышеприведённая команда создаст профиль *myqt*, который затем можно уже использовать:

```
qbs profile:myqt
```

после чего сделать его профилем по умолчанию и дополнительно задать путь сборки:

```
qbs config defaultProfile myqt
qbs install --clean-install-root --install-root $LOCAL_PREFIX release
```

**P. S.:** Правда у меня появляется ошибка:

> RROR: /home/qq/vreen/vreen.qbs:9:43 Value assigned to property 'vreen_version_major' does not have type 'string'.