# Как подключить Vreen в проект Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Как подключить Vreen в проект Qt?
Пытался сделать все по инструкции, но ничего не вышло. Так как инструкция для ОС Linux (Ubuntu), а у меня Windows и стоит компилятор Visual Studio.

Очень прошу, кто может дать инструкцию для установки Vreen для ОС Windows и компилятор Visual Studio

Comment: [Добате метку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/663067/edit) - windows.

Comment: Сделал. Благодарю

Comment: А это не [то](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552585/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-vreen-qt-vk-api)? Тоже под окнами.

Comment: Это тоже для терминала Линукса, а у меня Windows

Comment: Почему, там же написано - Windows и cmd?

Comment: @ProwuPomogite поставьте git for windows и у вас будет git bash - терминал линукса в винде.

Answer (score 1):

В самом Vreen я никаких платформозависимых вещей не вижу, инструкций, кстати, тоже. Вам скорее нужна инструкция к используемой среде сборки.

Vreen вроде бы заточен под [qbs](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/) (сборка описывается в Building Applications). Для этого у вас должен быть установлен и настроен qbs. Как вариант, можно установить QtCreator (он немного весит, а Qt всё-равно ставить надо), в нем настроить параметры компилятора и собрать проект при помощи qbs. Дальше уже можно подключать библиотеку к основному проекту стандартными для используемой среды разработки методами.

Можно попробовать использовать cmake, тогда нужно искать инструкцию по использованию qt + cmake (нужно правильно настроить переменные среды, чтобы cmake нашел qt и компилятор)